# Entity Framework Scalar Property Name change, changes Column Name?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

In EF, I would like to find out how within the designer I could change the name of my field, with out it changing my column name in the database? For example the name of my field for my model in code would be 'UnitPrice' and the database field name should remain as UNIT_PRICE. Please if anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just open up your Entity model(.edmx) in the designer(double click on it should do), select the column name you want to change and change the Name field in the Properties panel. Top tip -> if you right click on the table or the field in the designer you select Table Mapping from the context menu to see the mapping of database columns to the properties of your model. This answer assumes VS2010, not sure how this works in older versions, but should be doable.

Comment: when i change it, i checked my Edmx mapping section and sets both properties; 
    <ScalarProperty Name="UnitPrice" ColumnName="UnitPrice" /> When I reopen the solution it also changes my table mapping to UnitPrice

Comment: It appears this is happening when I generate database from Model. It changes the column name to the name of the property in the model. We are required to generate this file as a rule in my company,anyway to manipulate this transformation?

Comment: @Donny that sounds really strange. I have done this many times, yet I just tested again, all works fine in my setup. I'd try changing the property Name, saving then checking xml again. If you try to update your model from database after changing the mapping that also should work fine as long as you just add columns to your table, just choose the refresh tab in the update wizard. Other than that I'm out of ideas, good luck.